Do I need SDO to interface with SPI?
I am trying to use 3 AD5206 digital potentiometers in a multi sub-module configuration.
I was reading:
https://www.analog.com/en/resources/analog-dialogue/articles/introduction-to-spi-interface.html
For interfacing configurations.
and reading the data sheet for the AD5206, but got a bit confused, when I realized it does not appear that the AD5206 has an SDO pin. (Although the AD5204 does)
I'm just going to link up the SDI and Clock pins, and break out the individual Chip Select pins, and try that. I haven't done a whole lot with SPI, so I am curious about an potential situations I may be about to experience.
Your insight, and advice are welcome.

Do you need to read from the device?

You only need the SDO pin if you want to be able to read back the digital potentiometer settings.
I assume you don't need that. Then you are fine with your plan of linking up the SDI and CLK pins and breaking out the Chip Select pins.
